# Wait for thread to be available in the thread pool in java

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I am using executorservice for thread pooling in JAVA. Is there a way wherein I can wait for thread to be available in thread pool in executor service and only continue only when there are threads available in the pool

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of having an ExecutorService is not caring about handling threads so you should avoid to do so unless you have a very specific reason to keep track of their status.

Also you can add any number of task to the pool and the executor will run them all.

For example:

```
final List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>(10);
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) tasks.add(()->{
    //something time consuming
    return true;
});

final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<Future<Boolean> handles = executor.invokeAll(tasks);

for (Future<Boolean> handle : handles) {
    handle.get();
}

// here all the 10 tasks have been completed by the 5 thread pool
```

Note that every time a call to handle.get() returns, a thread in the pool is theoretically available but it will be instantaneously reused by the executor to run the next waiting task.

Comment: I have millions of tasks that needs to be executed. I only want to wait for threads to be available in the pool before adding more tasks to the executor service

Comment: I need fixed thread pool size so that I can use the thread pool name in my task to handle few things. I do not want to add threads or remove threads at runtime, I need fixed number of threads.

Comment: That is why I need to fix the number of threads as I am using it names in certain way in my program.

Comment: If you really want to do this (pro tip: you don't) then start submitting as much tasks as your thread count and add a new task every time a handle.get() returns.

Answer (score 0):

## This is an example of task that uses a ThreadPool and makes thread submiting work to wait when there is too much work waiting for available threads

This is useful in a scenario where is cheap to list [what to do] and time consuming to [do].

For instance:

- When you are running CPU intensive tasks and there is lots and lots of CPU available.
- When you are running tasks that depends on several slow API or datasources.

Java ThreadPools seems designed for the developer to submit the work in small batches and wait for the results (via Future.get or via ThreadPool.shutdown). There is no direct queue size control with blocking behavior. I believe this is what @Francesco Rogo was trying to explain to you. But there are workarounds. I found way easier to customize the threadpool to limit the size of the work queue and make the threads submiting the work to wait. I suspect you also want that.

```java
package lucas.examples.threadPool;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ExampleThreadPool {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        // Example resources:
        //  ThreadLocal<Sql> db001 = new ThreadLocal<Sql>() { protected Sql initialValue() { return DataSource001.instance.get(); }
        //  ThreadLocal<Sql> db002 = new ThreadLocal<Sql>() { protected Sql initialValue() { return DataSource002.instance.get(); }
            
        ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor( 
            /*nThreads=*/15, /*nThreads=*/15,  
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<>( /*work queue size=*/ 1 )
        );
        
        // Setup a thread factory to close the resources  
        pool.setThreadFactory( (r) -> {
            return new Thread( () -> {          
                r.run();            
                // Sql.close( db001 ) 
                // Sql.close( db002 ) 
            });
        } );
            
        // When the work queue is full, make the thread calling pool.execute() to wait 
        pool.setRejectedExecutionHandler( 
            (runnable,executor) -> { 
                try { 
                    executor.getQueue().put(runnable); 
                } catch( Exception e ) { 
                    throw new RuntimeException(e); 
                } 
            } 
        );

        // Simulates a work datasource 
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ ) {

            int i2 = i;
            
            System.out.println( "submit work..." + i2 );
                        
            pool.execute( () ->  {
                // start parallel processing 

                System.out.println( "begin execution of work..." + i2 );
                try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch( Exception e ) { }
                System.out.println( "end execution of work..." + i2 );

                // end parallel processing 
            } );

        }

        // IMPORTANT: wait all threads to finish the work before ending the program 
        pool.shutdown();

    }
}
```